# If formula not working for hospitality catering manager

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a spreadsheet for my Catering Manager.  For example, she can select one of three options for breakfast.  All she does is enter the quantity beside the option that the customer has selected.

On a separate sheet, I am trying to show a synopsis of everything that was selected for the day (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Refreshment Breaks, etc.).  There are tons of options, so I want this sheet to show ONLY what was selected.  My formula reads:

```
=IF(Sheet2!E10<10,
    "Breakfast Buffet",
    IF(Sheet1!E11<10,
       "Continental A",
       IF(Sheet1!E12<10,
          "Continental B")))
```

Regardless of where the quantity is input, my cell with the formula will ONLY say "Breakfast Buffet".

I hope I explained this simply enough.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If the result is always "Breakfast Buffet" it must mean the condition `E10<10` is always evaluating to TRUE. You may have to rethink that condition.

Comment: Depending on how the the data sheet is created, a pivot table might be a more usable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more or less correct to me. You did forget an ELSE-case for the last `IF()`, but I don't seem to have your problem:

Corrected formula: (beware that my regional settings require `;` instead of `,` in the formula):

```
=IF(Sheet2!E10<10; 
    "Breakfast Buffet";
    IF(Sheet1!E11<10;
       "Continental A";
       IF(Sheet1!E12<10;
          "Continental B";
          "Something else")))
```

Screenshot of "Sheet2":

[image]

You are aware that your formula refers both to "Sheet2" AND to "Sheet1", aren't you? :-) (looks like a typo to me)

Comment: FWIW, I have found `IFS()` to be much easier to use since it avoids all the nested parentheses. You have to use something like `TRUE,"Something Else"` for the final case as a stand-in for having an ELSE-case, but that's the only quirk. It may be worth mentioning as it may help the OP with similar problems in the future.